# Update multiple svn subfolders with one request

Tags: svn

In our course, we have a root folder 'course_name', and folders within that, one for each student, called 'student_id'. Each student has multiple labs, but while grading a single lab, I want to check out `course_name/student_id/lab_name`.

Currently, we first do a check out with immediate depth to get only the student folders (but not the lab  folders), and then do `svn up <list of student lab folders>`, but that creates a new request to the server each time. Is it possible to do it with a single request?

Answer (score 0):

Subversion has the ability to do *sparse checkouts* which makes it easy to checkout the root of the repository without getting tons of files:

```
 $ svn co --depth=immediates http://server/course_name
```

This will checkout `course_name`, and all of the student names under it, but won't checkout the labs. To get a particular lab, you can do:

```
$ cd course_name
$ svn up student_name/lab_name
```

If you wanted all the labs for a particular student, you could do:

```
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity student_name
```

The `--set-depth=infinity` allows you to check out all of the files in that tree.

Even if you had a few hundred students, and each student had 20 to 30 labs, I can't imagine checkout out the whole `course_name` would take that much time. For me personally, I might simply checkout the entire `course_name`, and this way, I have all of the students and their labs. As new labs come in, I'd do `svn up` and get them. That shouldn't take more than a minute or two with Subversion.

Comment: That's not what I want to do - as I mentioned in my question, we first do an immediate checkout and then update the respective labs and subfolders. The problem is when you say `svn up student1/lab student2/lab`, there are two requests sent to the server, two different updates. I want to do them in once to avoid having to do one update for each student. It currently takes several minutes, I was hoping to reduce this time. I personally keep my own copy of the entire repo, but this is particularly to grade a lab, where you don't want to waste time checking out all the labs

Comment: I can't understand your concern about _wasting time_. How long does it take to checkout the **entire** repository? I just checked out a 150Mb working directory with over 9000 files in under 90 seconds. Keep the working copy, and every time the students complete a lab, you do a `svn up`, and I bet the updates take less than a minute. I was thinking of doing a `svn ls -R` on the repo, `grep` out the labs, and the pass this off to `xargs svn up`, but you wouldn't save any time.

Comment: The updates are fine - but not all the course staff keeps the entire repository as I do, and we all run grader for the labs we are in charge of. We also need to checkout multiple revisions to grade with late penalties, meaning we have to do multiple checkouts.